# Linear Vertical Layout - Android

Tags: android-layout

In Android App development,I want to create a Linear Vertical layout as my main Screen
. and some 'n' textviews in it , and whenever i click on any of the textviews , it must direct to any of the layouts that I have created . How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is listview or recycler view for that. But as per your requirement, and as you mentioned N textviews, I am going to assume you want to create those text views programatically where N is dependant on some other parameter of your application. Here is how you do it:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView [] tvs = new TextView[N];

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_id_of_ll);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){                
            tvs[i] = new TextView(this); //this or reference to activity
            tvs[i].setText("TextView " + i);
            tvs[i].setLayoutParams(lpView);
            tvs[i].setTag(i);
            tvs[i].setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.addView(tvs[i]);

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
         int tag = (int)v.getTag();
         System.out.println("TextView with tag " + tag + " Clicked");
    }
}
```